# How do you handle optional file uploads with Sails JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, file-upload, sails.js

I have a form that a user can submit with or without a file.

The form:

```
<form method="post" action="/file/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="media" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The Controller

```
module.exports = {
  upload: function (req, res) {
    // Check if any files were uploaded
    if (!req.file('media')._files[0]) {
        return res.send('no file given!');
    }

    req.file('media').upload({
      dirname: '/tmp/uploads'
    },function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
      if (err) {
        sails.log.error('Error uploading file', err);
      }
      res.send('thanks for your file');
    });
  }
};
```

If they don't upload a file, I get the following error. There doesn't seem to be a way to catch it or suppress it unless I go into the skipper code and comment out the error throwing. **How can I submit the form without attaching a file and not crash the app?**

```
Error: EMAXBUFFER: An Upstream (`NOOP_media`) timed out before it was plugged into a receiver. It was still unused after waiting 4500ms. You can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` option.
```

I've been through a number of forums and blog posts but nothing has helped so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the check inside the `.upload()`. Remove the `if` statement.

```
req.file('media').upload({
  dirname: '/tmp/uploads'
}, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
  if(uploadedFiles.length === 0){ // Check the number of files uploaded.
    return res.send('no file given!');
  }
  if (err) {
    sails.log.error('Error uploading file', err);
  }
  return res.send('thanks for your file');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When a file input is left empty it seems to act like a normal text input and it will be empty so you can try checking for something like this:

```
 if(typeof req.param('media') !== 'undefined' && req.param('media').length == 0)) {
        return res.send('no file given!');
   }else {  //handle the file upload }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could abort the stream with `noMoreFiles()`.

```js
const skipperUpstream = req.file('media');

// skipperUpstream._files is an internal array containing the uploaded files for key `media`
// here i just expecting a single file, or none
const file = skipperUpstream._files[0];

if (!file) {
  // `skipperUpstream.__proto__` is `Upstream`. It provides `noMoreFiles()` to stop receiving files.
  // It also clears all timeouts: https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-skipper/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.skipper.Upstream.prototype.noMoreFiles
  skipperUpstream.noMoreFiles();
  return;
}

skipperUpstream.upload(/* your stuff */);
```